# Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I have a jenkins plugin that goes to slaves to pull from their workspace. It works fine on some linux slaves but fails on the windows slave :

```
Deploying artifact: http://djin-artifact01.dowjones.net:8081/artifactory/msi-snapshot-local/djin/dmi/windows/i386/packages/dmi/scheduler/dmi/scheduler-2.0.0-d.6.i386.msi
ERROR: remote file operation failed: w:\workspace\dmi-scheduler-ci-build at hudson.remoting.Channel@4788585d:windows-builder: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: w:\workspace\dmi-scheduler-ci-build at hudson.remoting.Channel@4788585d:windows-builder: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:977)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)
    at dj.pib.productivity.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:190)
    at dj.pib.productivity.generic.ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator$1.tearDown(ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java:356)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:171)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:169)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.writeTo(FileEntity.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:98)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:257)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClient.execute(PreemptiveHttpClient.java:88)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.execute(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:192)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.upload(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:188)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:524)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:299)
    at dj.pib.productivity.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:317)
    at dj.pib.productivity.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:288)
    at dj.pib.productivity.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:232)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2677)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to windows-builder(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1356)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:752)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:970)
    ... 9 more
```

Not sure what this error means? Why is it not able to access this remote workspace when it has no problem for some other slaves ? Totally lost on this, any ideas ?

Comment: The stacktrace indicates a communication error between the Windows slave and the Artifactory server happening during artifact deployment. Might be a firewall/proxy issue.

Comment: @drorb - the problem is that when I use the regular artifactory plugin, this happens without any issue but only in the custom plugin (my own) does this blow up.